# Manipulate hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that looks like

```
{
 "lt"=>"456",
 "c"=>"123",
 "system"=>{"pl"=>"valid-player-name", "plv"=>"player_version_1"},
 "usage"=>{"trace"=>"1", "cq"=>"versionid", "stream"=>"od", 
 "uid"=>"9", "pst"=>[["0", "1", "10"]], "dur"=>"0", "vt"=>"2"}
}
```

How can I go about turning it into a hash that looks like

```
{
 "lt"=>"456",
 "c"=>"123",
 "pl"=>"valid-player-name", 
 "plv"=>"player_version_1",
 "trace"=>"1", 
 "cq"=>"versionid", 
 "stream"=>"od", 
 "uid"=>"9", 
 "pst"=>[["0", "1", "10"]], "dur"=>"0", "vt"=>"2"
}
```

I basically want to get rid of the keys `system` and `usage` and keep what's nested inside them

Comment: Just to mention, there's an `}` additional in your expected ouput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Low-tech" version :)

```
h = { ... }
h.merge!(h.delete('system'))
h.merge!(h.delete('usage'))
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio, always love a low tech version :-), i thought delete would have deleted the whole nested hash, should have tried harder :-(

Comment: I know, let myself down a bit there really, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no rails:

```
hash.reject { |key, _| %w(system usage).include? key }.merge(hash['system']).merge(hash['usage'])
```

---

With active support:

```
hash.except('system', 'usage').merge(hash['system']).merge(hash['usage'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data has the same structure each time, I might opt for something simple and easy to understand like this:

```
def manipulate_hash(h)
  {
    "lt" => h["lt"],
    "c" => h["c"],
    "pl" => h["system"]["pl"],
    "plv" => h["system"]["plv"],
    "trace" => h["usage"]["trace"],
    "cq" => h["usage"]["cq"],
    "stream" => h["usage"]["stream"],
    "uid" => h["uid"],
    "pst" => h["pst"],
    "dur" => h["dur"],
    "vt" => h["vt"]
  }
end
```

I chose to make the hash using one big hash literal expression that spans multiple lines.  If you don't like that, you could build it up on multiple lines like this:

```
def manipulate_hash
  r = {}
  r["lt"] = h["lt"]
  r["c"] = h["c"]
  ...
  r
end
```

You might consider using fetch instead of the `[]` angle brackets.  That way, you'll get an exception if the expected key is missing from the hash.  For example, replace `h["lt"]` with `h.fetch("lt")`.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic version.

Merge any key that contains a hash:

```
h = { ... }

hnew = h.inject(h.dup) { |h2, (k, v)|
  h2.merge!(h2.delete(k)) if v.is_a?(Hash)
  h2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have an arbitrarily large list of keys to merge, this is an easily scaleable method:

```
["system", "usage"].each_with_object(myhash) do |key|
  myhash.merge!(myhash.delete(key))
end
```